# Cannot compile z3 library in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, z3

I would like to use the z3 4.4 managed API in a winforms application currently built with VS2008 (.net framework 3.5). I can use z3 in with .net 4.x applications without issues, but upgrading the current application to use .net 4.x is not currently feasible for reasons unrelated to z3. I am able to build the api and include Microsoft.z3.dll in my application. However, when compiling the z3 C++ library from the VS2008 command prompt, I get numerous errors where an attempt is made to implicitly convert a const_iterator to an iterator. Example:

> duality_solver.cpp
>   ..\src\duality\duality_solver.cpp(243) : error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator' to 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator'
>           with
>           [
>               _Traits=std::_Tset_traits,std::allocator,false>
>           ]
>           No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Changing std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator to std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator eliminates those errors. However, the resulting z3lib.dll copied to the bin\x86 directory of VS2008 project invariably produces the run-time error:

> Unable to load DLL 'libz3.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This also occurs if the libz3.dll is in the same directory as the api dll (Microsoft.z3.dll). I have also ensured that z3 and my project are built for same platform (x86). 
Using libz3.dll built with VS2013 produces the same run-time error above in the VS2008 project. Can z3 version 4.4.0 be used in a Visual Studio 2008 project? If so, how can I ensure that libz3.dll can be loaded to avoid the error above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't build and test on VS 2008, and furthermore will at some 
point move to C++ language features that are not supported 
on old platforms (but supported across operating systems and 
newer compilers).

On one of my machines, I use a community (free) version of VS2013 to build Z3.

Comment: Thank you @NikolajBjorner. I suppose I will need to decide if I can wait until my project is ready to migrate to a modern development platform or find an SMT solver I can use now.

Comment: On the off chance that you're also using Windows XP or older, Z3 will not work on those platforms, regardless of the version of Visual Studio, because the .dll uses thread local storage which is not supported on these old platforms, so a DLL built on a newer platform will not work either. When this is the case, the system will simply complain about not being able to load the DLL, but without any further detail.

Comment: You can also download old versions of Z3 from here:
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/old/older_z3.html